# laravel have both Input::old('') and value of text input on form

Tags: php, post, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form that will pull data from the database as well as submit new data to overwrite the old all in the same fields. For example:

```
{{ Form::text('date', Input::old('date'),  array('id' => 'date'))}}
```

Where the second parameter includes both the value from the database $i->date and also the input:old validator to ensure it wasn't left blank by accident.

Is there a way to do this? I already tried using an array as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should consider [**form model binding**](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding) `Form::model` instead of `Form::open`.

Also you can leave your input value alone:

```
{{ Form::text('date', null,  array('id' => 'date'))}}
```

**Controller side example**:

```
$model = new Model;
return View::make('layout', compact('model'));
```

**Way of opening the form**:

```
{{ Form::model($model) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but will this work?

[Form model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding)

```
{{ Form::model($yourmodel, array('route' => array('yourmodel.update', $yourmodel->id))) }}

{{ Form::text('date', Input::old('date'), null, array('id' => 'date')) }}
```

from the docs

> If there is an item in the Session flash data matching the input
>   name, that will take precedence over the model's value. So, the
>   priority looks like this:
>
> Session Flash Data (Old Input) Explicitly Passed Value Model Attribute
>   Data